# Установка кодировки в java коде

Tags: java, файлы, парсер, кодировка

Имеется код который выполняет поиск строк в файле:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    char z;
    String su="";
    String search = "milk";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Влад\\Desktop\\txt.txt");

    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)){
        int content;
        while((content = fis.read())!= -1){
            z = (char)content;
            su += String.valueOf(z);
            if(su.contains("\r\n")){
                su = "";
            }
            if(su.contains(search)){
                System.out.println(search);
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Файл txt Содержит в себе:

```
test

Ворона

Мясо
Молоко
```

Но в последствии выяснилось, что `.contains()` в переменную `su` также в виде текстовой информации поступают отступы и т.д. Да и в целом все символы там смешиваются в одну кучу и получается как то вот так:

```
test

Âîðîíà

Ìÿñî
```

Только еще с символами абзацных отступов меж словами(Они отказались копироваться)
Я пришел к выводу, что мне нужно установить кодировку utf_8.

Собственно вопрос: Как установить кодировку в Java коде?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

Comment: @post_zeew напишите ответ, пожалуйста, а не кидайте просто ссылку

Comment: @AlexChermenin, Когда есть время -- я пишу ответ, когда нет -- могу оставить ссылку, и ,считаю, что это тоже полезно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8");
```